# How to use ES6 import/export with Webpack 4?

Tags: webpack, es6-modules, webpack-4

I'm trying to get a basic ES6 `import`/`export` working with Webpack 4, and Webpack can't seem to resolve my module, though per the error message it's looking right at it:

```
$ make
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production src/app.js -o dist/bundle.js
Hash: 6decf05b399fcbd42b01
Version: webpack 4.1.1
Time: 339ms
Built at: 2018-3-11 14:50:58
 1 asset
 Entrypoint main = bundle.js
    [0] ./src/app.js 41 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./src/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hello.js' in '/home/(myhomedir)/code/js/src'
 @ ./src/app.js 1:0-31 2:0-5
```

Here's my setup (`node_modules`, `dist` etc. omitted):

```
$ npm ls --depth=0
.
├── webpack@4.1.1
└── webpack-cli@2.0.11

$ tree
.
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── app.js
    └── hello.js
```

Makefile:

```
webpack = ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode production
entry = src/app.js

webpack: $(entry)
    $(webpack) $(entry) -o dist/bundle.js
```

src/app.js:

```
import {hello} from "hello.js";
hello();
```

src/hello.js:

```
function hello() {
    alert("yes it's hello");
}
export { hello };
```

I've tried many variations on the import path in `app.js`, but they all get the same result: `Can't resolve` the module file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to transpile it using babel & use [babel-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx).

Also, you don't need to use **make** just use **npm scripts**.

There are mistakes like importing `import { hello } from 'hello.js'` instead it should be `import { hello } from './hello.js'` or without **.js** like `import { hello } from './hello'`

Try the following -

**npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-preset-env webpack@next webpack-cli**

## src/app.js

```
import { hello } from "./hello";
hello();
```

## src/hello.js

```
function hello() {
  console.log("yes it's hello");
}
export { hello };
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/app.js",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "node dist/bundle.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.11"
  }
}
```

## .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

First run `npm run build` or `npm run prod` & then run `npm run start` which will log the output

Comment: ./ (as in import { hello } from "./hello.js") was all it needed. Thanks!

Comment: upvote it if its correct. also sooner webpack 4 will be used in a month or so & `babel-preset-env` will be all you will need so don't use old practices because soon it will be changing & upload you code like mine

Answer (score 3):

The modern solution is to use node.js 13+, then add `"type": "module"` to your package.json file. This will allow you to use import syntax instead of require. More info here https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/esm.html

Webpack still needs the require syntax, so you will have to rename `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.cjs` and then let webpack know what's the new config file by adding `webpack --config webpack.config.cjs` to your package.json script command. Keep an eye here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1165 if webpack fixes their issue with require

This means you don't need any babel or any transpiler.